# How to Disable ASP.net AJAX Framework in ASP.net 3.5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-3.5

I'm working on an ASP.net 3.5 website with MooTools as the AJAX framework. I want to disable ASP.net's AJAX framework so it behaves more like ASP.net 2.0.  This is to decrease page loading times and to reduce incompatibilities.  Is this possible and if so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to remove the System.Web.Extensions assembly from the references, and then I found and removed all instances of the ScriptManager control.

Once I did this, none of the AJAX framework stuff is rendered to the pages.

I wanted to keep 3.5 for LINQ and other jazz, so just targeting the 2.0 framework wouldn't work.

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some articles on how to improve the performance of asp.net ajax in the .net 3.5 framework. Just can't find the link. But there are some changes you can do in the web.config which will improve performance wise. But, if you want to use MooTools, i guess you can just remove the Assemblies and the remove all references in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this.
If you are using Visual Studio 2008 when you create projects/websites make sure you target .net framework 2.0. If you do not use any of the controls/extenders with framework 3.5 you will not reference any 3.5 assemblies. To be sure of that take a look at the web.config file and settle issues.

I see that you are looking to use moo tools, the above mentioned settings and jquery for your custom javascript stuff should get your job done.

Thats all I can say per my knowledge.

Happy coding!