# Webbrowser control in C# weird behavior

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm setting a HTML string value to webbrowser.DocumentText. Problem is, sometimes it worked and sometimes it hangs up and not go through the documentcompleted event. what might be the problem?

Please reply, asap..

Thanks,

Jepe

Comment: do you have a sample DocumentText that's causing problems for us?

Comment: And could you show the code causing the problem? How exactly does the "hang" look like?

Comment: I can't post the sample documenttext but it's just basic html with javascript and css. When i set the documenttext, nothing happens and the documentcompleted never triggred. is html rendered in documenttext might cause the problem?

Comment: Try turning off AJAX, if any?

Comment: @Jepe: Remove all references that makes AJAX calls. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337896/how-to-disable-asp-net-ajax-framework-in-asp-net-3-5/338394#338394

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: With all the web-'dynam-ism' nowadays, a page is never really in a 'completely-loaded' state. After DocumentComplete, the OnLoad event of the page is fired, then any scripts placed in such an event are fired, and then javascript timers may be used to initiate download/upload of some resource, or a change in page using AJAX, etc.

I believe AJAX calls could cause all kinds of unseen problems with your `WebBrowser` control; because AJAX can cause multiple `Navigating()` events to fire during the loading of a page. And for that reason your app would experience multiple `DocumentCompleted` event fire on that page.

A possible solution could be to monitor the page changes and attempt to find out what possibly got changed. And to do this you may need to look into [Notify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704258%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.

> Called by MSHTML when a change occurs
>   in the contents of the markup
>   container  with which it is
>   associated.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/5fe3e7a1-b3c7-4083-9a00-7a72bf833a9c/) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/d91f3553-0981-4587-a800-83ac6fd4ed8a#) discussion may help you coming up with something like following:

```
HtmlElement target = _webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("somedivthatwillbepopulatedbytheajaxrequest");

if (target != null)
{ 
    target.AttachEventHandler("onpropertychange", new EventHandler(handler));
}
```